# Using Bokeh for a dropdown menu which would create different charts

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to create a dropdown interface for my work. My dataset looks like this, it is a random dataset

[image]

Now I would like 2 dropdowns say CNN and BBC here. After selecting a channel from dropdown, I would like to select a Topic which would produce a bar chart according to it's value.

I am trying to access just one value initially, but it gives me a blank graph.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.io import output_notebook,show,output_file

p=figure()

import csv
data = [row for row in csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Aishwarya/Documents/books/books_q4/crowd_computing/Bokeh-Python-Visualization-master/interactive/data/data.csv', 'r',encoding="utf8"))]

p.vbar(x=data[1][2], width=0.5, bottom=0,
            top=data[1][1], color="firebrick")

#output_notebook()
output_file('1.html')

show(p)
```

Comment: is your question about two dropdown menus or why the barplot not working? need some idea about your data - please include a sample in the post.

Comment: Barplot not working. I don't have the dataset produced yet. The sample of the dataset has been included in the image above.

Comment: this is your 'data' varaible and csv file content I was asking about, can you provide the sample?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two issues going on:

- The first is that if you are using categorical coordinates on an axis, e.g. "CNN" which it appears you are expecting to use, then you need to etll Bokeh what the categorical range is:

  ```
  p.figure(x_range=["CNN", ...]) # list all the factors for x_range
  ```

  If you need to update the axis later you can update the range directly:

  ```
  p.x_range.factors = [...]
  ```
- Additionally, as of Bokeh `0.13.0` there is a current open issue that prevents "single" factors from working as coordinates: [**`#6660`** Coordinates should accept single categorical values](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6660). The upshot is that you will have to put the data in a Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` explicityl (always an option), or in this case a workaround is also just to pass a single-item list instead:

  ```
  p.vbar(x=["cnn"], ...)
  ```

Here is a complete update of your code, with some fake data put in:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show

p = figure(x_range=["cnn"])

p.vbar(x=["cnn"], width=0.5, bottom=0, top=10, color="firebrick")

show(p)
```

[image]

I would also recommend studying the User's guide section [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html).